# Home / end control characters don't work in emacs under Mac OS X terminal

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm running emacs from within a terminal window on Mac OS X. From the bash shell at the same terminal, I can use `Shift + <Home>` and `Shift + <end>` to go to the beginning and end of the line respectively. When I'm inside emacs, these don't work. I get the error:

```
M-[ h is undefined
```

and

```
M-[ f is undefined
```

Is this the fault of emacs or the terminal emulator? I can see how to change the control characters that the terminal sends, but as far as I can tell these are the right control characters to send (and it works outside of emacs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put these in your .emacs:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[ h") 'beginning-of-line)                                 
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[ f") 'end-of-line)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, when I use either one I end up with the mark being set so that all text between the original cursor position and the end / beginning of the line becomes selected.

Comment: Hm, I picked those functions out of the help, they are proabably the wrong ones.  You can find the correct ones with describe-key: in an emacs which does what you want, \h-k and type the key combination, it will tell you the function being called.

Comment: The problem is not the functions. The problem is the case. When you press `Home`, it's actually generating `M-[ H` and treating that as Shift + `M-[ h`. Holding down Shift in emacs while moving the cursor causes it to create a selection. The solution is to use `(kbd "M-[ H")` and `(kbd "M-[ F")`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's a problem with Terminal.app as I've got some similar problems with it. I don't know how to fix it, but for your particular problem, you can use C-a and C-e to go to the beginning and end of line, respectively.

Comment: In fact, `C-a` is problematic because I'm running inside screen - though of course I could remap the screen default control character.

Comment: Yeah, that's always a bit annoying. Remapping works, and there's `C-a a` as well.