# How to rebind C-a and C-e in emacs back to Home and End on mac?

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-mavericks, emacs24

I am using logitech pc keyboard with my eMac and want to use Home and End buttons as usual. I've already rebound them for mac terminal. And want to rebind them in emacs as well.

Comment: Tis question is a bit unclear. Do you want to bind Home to `beginning-of-line`, or do you want to change the binding of `C-a`? (I find it hard to believe that you're running OS X Server on an eMac.)

Comment: Sorry. There was not tag `mac-os-x` so I used which was present. Now I see also `osx` tag. Corrected. Frankly speaking. I do not need C-a in my emacs cause it conflicts with `screen` tool. But the main goal is to bind Home/End keys.

Comment: I always rebound in `screen` instead of emacs when I used it. (I gave `screen` up for tmux; tmux and iTerm 2 is a very nice combo). Plus, `C-a` is move-beginning-of-line in all Cocoa text, and it helps to be consistent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Home / end control characters don't work in emacs under Mac OS X terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614150/home-end-control-characters-dont-work-in-emacs-under-mac-os-x-terminal)

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
(global-set-key [home] 'move-beginning-of-line)
(global-set-key [end] 'move-end-of-line)
```

As for Terminal.app, its default key bindings grab <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> for itself (to scroll to the beginning and end of the terminal output), and lets <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>End</kbd> through to the application.  You can switch this around in under "Settings" -> "Keyboard" in the Terminal preferences.

Comment: Thank you. Workin but partially. Does not work in Terminal.app :(

Comment: What do you mean? I have already bound in Settings->Keyboard [arrow to the left upper corner] (or home on mykeyboard) to tthe same value as shift-home bound (\033[H) and end corresponding. So my home/end keys working well in shell. But not well in emacs :(

Comment: Hm, that's weird.  What do you get if you type `C-h c` and then hit the home/end key?

Answer (score 2):

In your .emacs file put something like this:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
      '(lambda ()


         (define-key global-map [C-home] 'beginning-of-buffer)
         (define-key global-map [C-end] 'end-of-buffer)
         (define-key global-map [home] 'beginning-of-line)
         (define-key global-map [end] 'end-of-line)


         ;;; much more semi private stuff deleted

         ))
```

It works for me since ancient times.